Difficulties understanding how smooths are generated using ordered factor-smooth interactions in gamm() from mgcv
I am trying to use gamm() from the mgcv package to quantitatively compare the gamm() trajectories (shape) of different brain regions. I am using longitudinal data. Prior resources by Dr. Gavin Simpson have outlined how factor-smooth interactions can be performed using gam() and ordered factors (ie: gam(y ~ of + s(x) + s(x, by = of), data = df)). In the context of my project, I envision using factor-smooth interactions where "x" represents age (years) and "of" represents the ordered factor of "region". This would look like:
LamyvsRamygamm_zscore <- gamm(volZ ~ s(age) + s(age, by = oLamy) + oLamy + ICVZ, data = comparativeGAMM_LamyVRamy, method = "REML", random = list(sub=~1, scan=~1))
volZ = standardized volume values (dependent variable)
age = age in years
Lamy = ordered factor variable for region that is coded as either 0 or 1 depending on brain region
ICVZ = standardized measurement for intracranial volume, this is a covariate I want to control for in my models
sub = participant ID (random effect for longitudinal data)
scan = unique scan ID (random effect for unique scan IDs because they are included twice, once for first region and a second time for second region)
From my understanding, the use of an ordered factor-smooth interaction would make one of my regions of interest the reference level (represented in the s(age) term) and the second region a second level that would be compared to the reference level to produce a smooth that captures the difference between those two smooths. Based on Gavin Simpson's blog post, I expected that when I ran this, 2 smooths should be produced when plot(LamyvsRamygamm_zscore$gam) is run: one smooth that represents the reference level and another smooth that represents the difference between the reference level and second level. However, when I run this model and plot it, the following plots are produced:


I am also including plots of the individual trajectories of these two regions that are produced with the following gamm() models:
Lamygamm_nointeraction_nomale_zscore <- gamm(LamyvolZ ~ s(age) + ICVZ, data = mastersheet, method = "REML", random = list(sub=~1))

Ramygamm_nointeraction_nomale_zscore <- gamm(RamyvolZ ~ s(age) + ICVZ, data = mastersheet, method = "REML", random = list(sub=~1))



You can see that the first plot produced by the factor-smooth interaction does not look identical to either of the plots produced by the region-specific gamm()s. In my opinion, it almost looks like a combination of the two.
Can someone help me understand what is going on here? Does using the ordered factor make the reference smooth some combination of both levels? Or is this discrepancy due to a lack of capability between ordered factor-smooths interactions and the gamm() function? Is there a better way for me to perform factor-smooth interactions with gamm()?

There are two things going on here:

In the separate models the basis for the smooths is built from only the data available in the respective level (brain area). In the ordered by model, the basis for the reference and difference smooths is formed from all the data. This can introduce subtle differences,

I would argue that the top pair of plots are quite similar; for some reason the model fitted to region 0 only is a little smoother but qualitatively the estimated effects are quite similar.


Is a Gaussian model appropriate for a response that is a volume? I would expect the variance in a volume would scale proportionally with the mean volume. gamm() is only really useful for Gaussian GAMMs (perhaps it's OK for a Gamma GAMM). I would proceed by fitting the volume with a model with family = Gamma("log") using gamm4::gamm4(), which is in the gamm4 package also by Simon Wood, which uses the lme4 pakage for fitting the GAMM. You could also switch to fitting with gam(), or bam() if data size is an issue, and family = Gamma("log") to also check the fitted functions.
There might be a way to use a numeric by to trick gam()/gamm() into fitting a similar model to the ordered factor, but I need to refresh my memory  as to exactly what it would be doing.
